# Unable to set net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max from privilege init container in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I faced with an issue related to modifying kernel params using init container.

I’m using busybox **privileged** container to modify some kernel parameters. When I’m trying to change **net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max** parameter I’m getting error:

```
sysctl: error setting key 'net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max': Permission denied
```

All other kernel parameters can be changed without problems(somaxconn and etc.)

Spend a lot of time to find a solution but no luck. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max` from an init container as it an "unnamespaced" parameter.  You should be able to set it using a privileged DaemonSet on each node.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `hostNetwork: true` to the spec section in the pod template to allow the pods to access node's network namespace.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-policy/#host-namespaces